# How to set the format of JSON post method in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I'm sending a post request through webservices but I'm not getting the response I want.

Here's my code:

```
NSString *newurlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"asit\",\"email\":\"m.kulkarni@easternenterprise.com\",\"businessType\":\"1\",\"score\":30}"];
NSString * url = @"http://www.nieuwe-dag.nl/mobile_be/public/?action=saveScore";
//NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&businessType=%d&score=%d",name, email, bussinesstype, score];

NSData *postData = [newurlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSLog(@"urlString::%@",newurlString);
NSLog(@"postLength::%@",postLength);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:300];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *theConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (theConnection){
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the request type to json but you are not creating a json. The data you are creating is just nsstring. I think you need to create a json object. You can download JSON API from here:

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Use [SBJSONWriter dataWithObject:] to create a JSON object. Then pass it to your request.

FOr more info on JSON:

http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need proper *postData*

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = @{
    @"name": @"asit", 
    @"email": @"m.kulkarni@easternenterprise.com",
    @"businessType": @"1",
    @"score": @(30)
};

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict options:0 error:nil];
```